# Drupal 8 template for content-type stored in module

Tags: php, drupal, twig, drupal-modules, drupal-8

I am building a simple module with features in drupal 8. Basically it is just a content-type with some fields exported with the features module. 
now i am trying to store a template for this content type IN my costume module to make the module reusable in other projects. **All in all**: i want to store the template for my content type in the module and not in the theme. (in an own templates/ directory)

In Drupal 7 the approach was made with something like this:

```
function mymodule_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
  'node__mycontenttypemachinename' => array(
      'render element' => 'elements',
      'template' => 'node--mycontenttypemachinename', //removed the "templates/"
      'base hook' => 'node' //this line did the job
    )
  );
}
```

i found [this post](https://www.drupal.org/node/2640110) on the drupal site, but i am not sure if it is the correct way to reach what i want. and if it is the way (i tried this of course), can someone explain how to get it work. i have some issues with this part:

> Step #2: Call the Template
>   In the place where you are returning your render array (whether from a controller method that is called from your router yml file, or wherever), make a call to your twig template.

help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**
I tried the Drupal 7 way. Drupal recognices the template, in the twig-debug I can see it is using my template. **Problem:** I can enter some HTML there; but if I try to use this for example: `{{ content }}` I see nothing. In my theme´s template-folder this is working. any ideas?

**EDIT 2:**
I added the missing line in my code-example above. For everyone how wants to reach the same like me.

**solved**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will answer this myself.

I was missing the *base hook* for theming.

```
'base hook' => 'node'
```

I edited the example code in my question for everybody who has the same issue.

Comment: I'm getting the error Fatal error: Call to a member function bundle() on null in path-to/drupal-8.3/core/modules/node/node.module on line 566. what is the issue here?